# Mirror directory structure in pdf bookmarks using iText

Tags: c#, itext

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
\- root
  |- 1. Folder1
  \- 2. Folder2
  ||- 2.1 Folder21
  ||   file.pdf
  |\- 2.2 Folder22
  || |- 2.2.1 Folder 221
  || |- 2.2.2 Folder 222
  ||    otherFile.pdf
  ||    yetAnotherFile.pdf
  ||- 2.3 Folder23       
  |- 3. Folder3
```

I want to create a pdf containing all the pdfs in the folders, combine them into one pdf and also create a bookmark structure that mirrors the layout of the files and folders in the file system.

**What's already working:**

- Concatenate all the pdfs in the folders into result.pdf
- Place bookmarks in result.pdf to jump to the page in result.pdf where the respective "sub-pdfs" now begin.

**Where I have troubles:**

- Placing the bookmarks in a hierachy, similar to how they are laid out in the file system.

Here is my tree data structure:

```
class TreeNode : IEnumerable<TreeNode> {
    private readonly List<TreeNode> children = new List<TreeNode>();

    readonly List<string> files;

    private string Id;
    private TreeNode Parent { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(string id) {
        Id = id;
        files = Directory.GetFiles(id, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderBy(f => f).ToList();
    }

    public TreeNode Add(TreeNode item) {
        item.Parent = this;
        children.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TreeNode> GetEnumerator() {
        return children.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count => children.Count;
    public int FileCount => files.Count;
}
```

I build my tree with these functions:

```
private static TreeNode BuildTree(string path) {
        var root = new TreeNode(path);
        TraverseDir(root);

        return root;
    }

private static void TraverseDir(TreeNode parent) {
        var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parent.Id).OrderBy(f => f);
        foreach (var dir in dirs) {
            var tmp = parent.Add(new TreeNode(dir));
            TraverseDir(tmp);
}}
```

And this is finally my first try to build the hierachy with iText:

```
private static List<Dictionary<string, object>> traverse(TreeNode tree) {
        var outlines = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var bm = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            {"Title", tree.Id}
        };

        var kids = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        foreach (var child in tree.children) {
            var c = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                {"Title", child.Id}
            };
            kids.Add(c);
            traverse(child);
        }
        bm.Add("Kids", kids);

        outlines.Add(bm);
        return outlines;
    }
```

This only creates the first level of the hierachy, i.e.

```
\- root
 |- 1. Folder1
 |- 2. Folder2
 |- 3. Folder3
```

The outline data structure that iText expects is a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. Child nodes are attached in the `Kids` key of particular dictionary.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?